# How can this be re-written as an ActiveRecord query? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have the following method in a controller:

```
# GET /units/1
def show
    @unit = Unit.find(params[:id]

    @product_instances = Array.new
    current_user.product_instances.each do |product_instance|
        if product_instance.product.unit == @unit
            @product_instances.push(product_instance)
        end
    end

    ... #rest of method
end
```

As can be seen, I have four tables/models: User, Product, ProductInstance, and Unit. A User has many ProductInstances. Each ProductInstance maps to a Product. A Unit has many Products.

I would like to fetch only the User's ProductInstances that are linked to a Product in the current Unit. The current code does it, but how can I re-write it better? I'd like to get rid of the for-each loop and if statement and replace it with chained ActiveRecord queries, if possible.

I tried something like below but it didn't work:

```
@product_instances = current_user.product_instances.where(:product.unit => @unit)
```

Seems you cannot do `:product.unit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this

```
current_user.product_instances.joins(:product).where("products.unit_id = ?",@unit.id)
```

or with hashes

```
current_user.product_instances.joins(:product).where(:products => {:unit_id => @unit.id})
```

Comment: Nope, get this error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: product.unit`

Comment: Did you try the line i suggested above? I havent used "product.unit" in my suggested solution anywhere

Comment: Oops. Okay, it works. Thankyou. Is there any way to use symbols instead of the string `"products.unit_id = ?"`.

Comment: you could try -> where(:products.unit_id => @unit.id) but i'm a bit old fashioned :)

Comment: and oh! feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Hmmm, that does not work. I get the error `undefined method 'unit_id' for :products:Symbol`. I'm confused as to why the string approach would work but not the symbol approach.

Comment: Not sure sir! If it were more acceptable in this world i'd keep myself closer to SQL more. Less complecting anyday.